# How do I treat a layout as a view?

Tags: android

I'm making a chathead-esque app and it works just fine with a single view, e.g. an ImageView, but how do I use a whole layout? I tried adding an id to the layout, but nope.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
 windowManager.addContentView(R.layout.popup, params);
```

Comment: Please post your code or explain what exactly you want to do with that layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inflate the layout. Like

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View myLayoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.MY_LAYOUT_ID, null, false);
```

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)

Then use

```
View view = myLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.your_view_id);
```

Comment: Worked, but views on the layout don't work when I try to use them.

Comment: myLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.yourViewID);